# Woo commerce new user email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I wrote a custom plugin that handles login and registration for my WordPress Woocommerce site.

When a user registers via my custom form handler I would like to trigger Woocommerce to send the new user an email instead of using wp_mail. This way I reduce code redundancy, and all of the transactional emails can be formatted the same (they all have the same look and feel).

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$wc = new WC_Emails();
$wc->customer_new_account($user_id);
```

$customerID should be the ID of the newly created customer. Here you can find out everything about the WC_Email_Customer_New_Account class: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email_Customer_New_Account.html. Just place this code somewhere where it will run after the customer has been registered, so I assume somewhere where you would have placed the wp_mail functions. Let me know if this helped :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried it, however, I received this error. "
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Email_Customer_New_Account' not found". You pointed in the right direction. The following works though, "$wc = new WC_Emails();  $wc->customer_new_account($user_id);"

Comment: Glad I could help, I will edit the post with the updated code.