# Send woocommerce new user email instead of wordpress new user email

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

When I create a new user manually through wordpress admin dahsboard or if someone registers on my site using their social account (using Nextend Social Login plugin), the default wordpress new user email is sent to the customer.

I would like to send the woocommerce new user email instead.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woo commerce new user email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226823/woo-commerce-new-user-email)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your coding skills. So maybe you could take a look at [Better Notification for Wordpress](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/).

For example, it allows you to edit email for a particular event/action (like add user, or register), among other things.